# Azure Easy Tables - App loads data only on one emulator

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have implemented loading data from Azure Easy Tables in my Xamarin.Forms app. 
App loads data which depends on their parameters (name). 
The app only works fine on one Android emulator (Android 6.0 API 23). When I run it on other Android emulator even with the same Android version the data wont't load. All emulators are connected to internet.

Even real device can not load data.

Is the problem somewhere on Azure, Code or ?

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: I can't reproduce. Do you have more details?

Comment: The app has to check if row exists in Azure Easy Tables. App sends name of the row to Azure and on one Android emulator it gets that row exists and it really exists in Azure Easy Tables. But on other Android emulator (with the same Android version) it always gets that row doesn't exist.